# How to set a descripton to an objective from imsmanifest.xml

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, articulate-storyline

I'm new on this SCORM 2004 3rd edition thing and i'm needing to add the description in every objective i create.
http://www.examengine.net/help/LmsApiHelp/GetValueEnum.htm This makes me believe that i can create it from the js API but i want to know if i can create it from imsmanifest.xml

The SCO(s) was created on Articulate Storyline, normally i can't do objectives on it but triggering javascript i'm able to set it, but now I need to show de description from imsmanifest.

I found this:

```
<imsss:objective objectiveID="obj_module_1" description=”This is the first objective of module 1.”>
```

but it doesn't work...

I used this function to get it:

```
lmsAPI.GetObjectiveDescription("obj_module_1");
```

Comment: Do any of these example courses contain what you're looking for? http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/

Comment: No, none of them uses description attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a description attribute for objectives in SCORM. The SCORM Content Aggregation Model (CAM) book lists the elements and attributes available for a manifest. From what it lists the only attributes for 'objective' are `objectiveID` and `satisfiedByMeasure`. ([SCORM books here](http://www.adlnet.org/scorm/scorm-2004-4th.html))

Unless your LMS is offering this as a feature beyond SCORM, it looks like the Javascript path is your only option.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, the cmi data model has defined "cmi.objectives.n.description" http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/ , what's the meaning of that?

Comment: You're right that it's the holder for an objectives description. But SCORM doesn't give you a way to set that value other than through the run-time API - meaning, you can't set it in the manifest, like the question asks.